Movie with a super potion makes old car go super speed
In this movie there is a guy who is like a cartoonist , kind of a loner. He draws about a lady thief and then meets someone somewhat similar. The only scene I remember clearly is that there is this super potion they pour it into the engine of an old car which makes it go super speed and at the end of journey they show that the the car engine is totally fried and melting away. Been searching for this one for the past 10+yrs any help is appreciated.


This is the movie which you are looking for:
Source IMDB:

The panther's old car breaks down in the middle of the street. Meanwhile, Dr. Jekyll has developed a magic potion which transforms him into the mean Mr. Hyde. He pours the same drink into his car, and it transforms into a big and mean speed machine. He then goes to a used-car salesman and trades in the car for a new one. The salesman intends to sell the old car for a large sum, but when the car transforms back into its old, compact shape, the salesman lowers the price - and that's when the panther notices it. He buys the car, which soon transforms into its fast and dangerous shape. The panther gets chased by the police but manages to escape when the car shape-shifts back into its normal shape. When the car again gets mean, the panther stops the car at the red light, hops out, but gets chased by the car. When the car finally runs out of gas, the panther, relieved, goes into a..

MORE...

Sorry mate not the same movie, in this one the car doesn't transform it looks the same but goes super speed also its only used once for when the main characters needs to get some place asap.Anyways thank you for your efforts.
